# Why can't I use my server name (SQL Server)?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I'm about to study how to join tables from multiple, different databases. So the way I refer to a particular table is by following this format **db_server_name.db_name.schema_name.table_name**. So after searching around how to get the server name using this command :

```
SELECT @@SERVERNAME
```

I got the following server name:

```
LAPTOP-FV8FREL6\SQLEXPRESS
```

Also this confirms:

[image]

So I did this query :

```
select v.VendorID, v.VendorName
from LAPTOP-FV8FREL6\SQLEXPRESS.AP.dbo.Vendors v;
```

But it says

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 6 Incorrect syntax near '-'.

Do you know how to get this works?

Comment: Have you tried wrapping your machine name in `[]` so `[LAPTOP-FV8FREL6\SQLEXPRESS].AP.dbo.Vendors`?

Comment: Why would you even want to put the server name in the query like this? If you use 4 part naming the first element is the server name. This is usually used for linked servers but you can use the server name of the current connection. I just don't see the point of putting the server in there when it is the local server.

Comment: Just for the sake of learning. I guess. I'm just following some instructions from a book I'm currently reading.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put [ ] around your server name.

```
select v.VendorID, v.VendorName
from [LAPTOP-FV8FREL6\SQLEXPRESS].AP.dbo.Vendors v;
```

Comment: Should be `select v.VendorID, v.VendorName from [LAPTOP-FV8FREL6\SQLEXPRESS].AP.dbo.Vendors v;`